# Email sending in aspnet identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-identity

I wrote following method to send emails

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(UserData user)
{
    try
    {
        #region Email content

        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(
        new MailAddress("sender@email.com", "Represent Location"),
        new MailAddress(Reciever_Email));
        m.Subject = "Mail Topic";

        m.IsBodyHtml = true;

        m.Body = string.Format("<img src=\"@@IMAGE@@\" alt=\"\"><BR/><BR/>Hi " + user.FirstName + "," + "<BR/><BR/>Your account has been successfully created with the Comp. Please click on the link below to access your account.<BR/><BR/>" + "Username - " + user.UserName + "<BR/>" + "Password - " + user.Password + "<BR/><BR/>" + "<a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">Please click here to Activate your account</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.UserEmail }, Request.Url.Scheme)) + string.Format("<BR/><BR/>Regards,<BR/>The Human Resource Department <BR/>");

        // create the INLINE attachment      
        string attachmentPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/logo.jpg");

        // generate the contentID string using the datetime
        string contentID = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath).Replace(".", "") + "@zofm";

        Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
        inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
        inline.ContentId = contentID;
        inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
        inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);
        m.Attachments.Add(inline);

        // replace the tag with the correct content ID
        m.Body = m.Body.Replace("@@IMAGE@@", "cid:" + contentID);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Email_Server_IP");
        smtp.Port = ServerPort;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@email.com", "sender_password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp.Send(m);

        #endregion

        return View(user);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

then I'm accessing above method in main controller like following

```
// Email Sending
UserData sampleData = new UserData();
sampleData.Id = user.Id;
sampleData.UserName = user.UserName;
sampleData.UserEmail = user.Email;
sampleData.FirstName = user.FirstName;
sampleData.Password = model.Password;

// await EmailController.Sendemail(sampleData);
var emailCntrl = new EmailController();
var sendEmail = emailCntrl.SendEmail(sampleData);
```

this is compiling without any compile times errors. but when I debug this I can see

in this line `m.Body = str...` I can see a error like this

[image]

because of that I'm getting an exception

> Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How can I solve this

Comment: Well given that there was no request added to controller before calling action, it would be null. What are you trying to do. Why create a controller only to call it internally? There is no need for a controller there. create a class to handle the email and pass in any dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Well given that there was no request added to controller before calling action, it would be null.

There is no need for a controller there just to send the email.

Create a class/service to handle the email and pass in any dependencies

```
public class EmailService {

    public UserData SendEmail(UserData user, string confirmationEmailUrl) {
        try
        {
            #region Email content

            MailMessage m = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress("sender@email.com", "Represent Location"),
            new MailAddress(Reciever_Email));
            m.Subject = "Mail Topic";

            m.IsBodyHtml = true;

            m.Body = string.Format("<img src=\"@@IMAGE@@\" alt=\"\"><BR/><BR/>Hi " + user.FirstName + "," + "<BR/><BR/>Your account has been successfully created. Please click on the link below to access your account.<BR/><BR/>" + "Username - " + user.UserName + "<BR/>" + "Password - " + user.Password + "<BR/><BR/>" + "<a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">Please click here to Activate your account</a>", user.UserName, confirmationEmailUrl + string.Format("<BR/><BR/>Regards,<BR/>The Human Resource Department <BR/>");

            // create the INLINE attachment      
            string attachmentPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/logo.jpg");

            // generate the contentID string using the datetime
            string contentID = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath).Replace(".", "") + "@zofm";

            Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
            inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
            inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
            inline.ContentId = contentID;
            inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
            inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentPath);
            m.Attachments.Add(inline);

            // replace the tag with the correct content ID
            m.Body = m.Body.Replace("@@IMAGE@@", "cid:" + contentID);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Email_Server_IP");
            smtp.Port = ServerPort;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sender@email.com", "sender_password");
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Send(m);

            #endregion

            return user;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

And get the action from main controller

```
// Email Sending
UserData sampleData = new UserData();
sampleData.Id = user.Id;
sampleData.UserName = user.UserName;
sampleData.UserEmail = user.Email;
sampleData.FirstName = user.FirstName;
sampleData.Password = model.Password;

var confirmationEmailUrl = Url.Link("Default", new { Action = "ConfirmEmail", Controller = "Account",  Token = sampleData.Id, Email = sampleData.UserEmail });

var emailService = new EmailService();
var user = emailService.SendEmail(sampleData, confirmationEmailUrl);
```

Comment: Nkosi I'm trying to call this inside web api controller method, [like this](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/XppG7)  then getting following errors `'UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and no extension method 'Action' accepting a first argument of type 'UrlHelper' could be found
'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Url' and no extension method 'Url' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found`

Comment: Updated to use the Link method. It also assumes that you have the Default convention-based route mapped for the account controller. Otherwise you just need to change that to what you can configured for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Request, because you create just `EmailController` class. When controller factory creates controller for request it passes request data to [Controller.Initialize Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx).

Of course the best practice is to create EmailService as was mentioned above, but as answer for your question, you can make workaround. You can pass `RequestContext` of parent controller to `EmailController` in constructor and call `Initialize`. It's going to look like.

```
    public EmailController()
    {
    }

    public EmailController(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

And in your controller

```
var emailCntrl = new EmailController(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
var sendEmail = emailCntrl.SendEmail(sampleData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just set the ControllerContext

```
var emailCntrl = new EmailController(){ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext};
var sendEmail = emailCntrl.SendEmail(sampleData);
```